# JSON DeserializeObject returns null

Tags: c#, json, xml, json-deserialization

I have a JSON response that is formatted like:

```
{
    "list": {
        "historySteps": [
            {
                "actualUserDisplayName": "John Doe",
                "actualUserID": "SiteOwner",
                "invokerType": "USER",
                "step": 10,
                "timestampFormatted": "09/23/2019 12:37:04 PM",
                "transitionName": "Work",
                "userDisplayName": "John Doe",
                "userID": "SiteOwner"
            },
            {
                "actualUserDisplayName": "John Doe",
                "actualUserID": "SiteOwner",
                "comments": "Zebra",
                "invokerType": "USER",
                "step": 9,
                "timestampFormatted": "09/23/2019 11:12:30 AM",
                "transitionName": "Return",
                "userDisplayName": "John Doe",
                "userID": "SiteOwner"
            },
            {
                "actualUserDisplayName": "John Doe",
                "actualUserID": "SiteOwner",
                "invokerType": "USER",
                "step": 1,
                "timestampFormatted": "09/23/2019 10:11:48 AM",
                "transitionName": "Initiate",
                "userDisplayName": "John Doe",
                "userID": "SiteOwner"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have C# code as:

```
public historyList GetWorkFlowHistory(string workspaceId, string dmsId)
{
    try {
    var client = new RestClient(TenantUrl + $"/api/rest/v1/workspaces/{workspaceId}/items/{dmsId}/workflows/history");
    client.Proxy = Proxy;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddCookie("customer", CustomerToken);
    request.AddCookie("JSESSIONID", SessionId);
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");


    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);


    if (response.ErrorException != null)
        throw response.ErrorException;
    else if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        throw new Exception(response.Content);

        var results = SimpleJson.SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<historyList>(response.Content);

        return results;

}
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.WriteLog("Exception in GetWorkFlowHistory() - " + ex.Message);
    }

    return null;

}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "historySteps")]
public class HistorySteps
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "actualUserDisplayName")]
    public string ActualUserDisplayName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "actualUserID")]
    public string ActualUserID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "comments")]
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "invokerType")]
    public string InvokerType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "step")]
    public string Step { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "timestampFormatted")]
    public string TimestampFormatted { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "transitionName")]
    public string TransitionName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "userDisplayName")]
    public string UserDisplayName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "userID")]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "list")]
public class historyList
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "historySteps")]
    public HistorySteps HistorySteps { get; set; }

}
```

The code works up to the point of response.Content where it retrieves the content. I can not figure out what I'm doin wrong when I'm attempting to DeserializeObject. It returns historySteps = null. What am I missing? Am I taking the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `public HistorySteps HistorySteps { get; set; }` is not a list change to `public List<HistorySteps> HistorySteps { get; set; }`.

Because SimpleJson is very... simple, you have to name your propertys exactly as the json and you will need a wrapper class for the `"list"` json .

```
public class HistorySteps
{
    public string actualUserDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string actualUserID { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
    public string invokerType { get; set; }
    public string step { get; set; }
    public string timestampFormatted { get; set; }
    public string transitionName { get; set; }
    public string userDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string userID { get; set; }
}

public class historyList
{
    public List<HistorySteps> historySteps { get; set; }
}

public class MyResponse
{
    public historyList list { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This still returned null results

Comment: This line is still perplexing me: var results = SimpleJson.SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<MyResponse>(response.Content); I would have thought the wrapper gets deserialized but it returns null.

Comment: @PigsIncorporated I just noticed that SimpleJson is very limited, please consider using [newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to have more freedom to name your properties differently from your json.

Comment: That was it. var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResponse>(response.Content); works perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are dealing with json, not xml. You should annotate your properties either with DataContract/DataMember or with JsonProperty.

Second, you are almost there, you just need an extra class that wraps the whole thing. "list" is a property *inside* the root object

Comment: Would the wrapper be a list or a property?

Comment: A class with a single property inside, named list, and of type historyList